# Split string into functions on parantheses, but not subfunctions

Tags: python, regex

I am cleaning a data set that consists of concatenated function calls strings that look like this: `"hello(data=x, capitalize = True)there()my(x = x)dear(x, 6L, ...)friend(x = c(1, 2, 3))"`. The goal is to split such a string into separate list elements, so that every function stands on its own.

So far I can split all functions that do not contain a subfunction (such as `"c(1,2,3)"`) using regex:

```
import re
s="hello(data=x, capitalize = True)there()my(x = x)dear(x, 6L, ...)"
t = re.findall(r"\w+\(.*?\)", s)

['hello(data=x, capitalize = True)', 'there()', 'my(x = x)', 'dear(x, 6L, ...)']
```

I am however stuck when a subfunction is included inside a function call such as `friend(x = c(1, 2, 3))"`, where the function is then split in half due to the subfunction instead of being preserved.

Is it possible to leave functions that contain other functions as substring intact using regex?

Comment: You could do this just by counting `(` and `)` couldn't you, and split when the count is balanced? I'm not sure how you've got this string in the first place but this looks prone for an AST rabbit hole

Comment: @roganjosh that sounds like a possible approach. how could that be implemented?

Comment: Can we assume that this is otherwise valid Python code *except* for a lack of newlines between function calls?

Comment: @chepner it is R-code unfortunately but it is otherwise completely valid. I simply need to "uncollapse" the functions back into their own elements or rows.

Comment: OK, you might want to see if you can find a parser for R code that can report the position of a syntax error, which you can use to split the string into a valid function call and remainder left to check.

Comment: I posted an answer for Python code; maybe you can adapt it if you find a suitable R parser.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without `regex` and just keeping a tally of how `(` and `)` are balanced. I don't know where that string comes from and I want to caveat this answer with - this is pretty crude and brittle - not my finest work. Then again, I suspect a `regex` approach would be too. It does what you want but more complex grammar is probably in such a file but you haven't given any indication of that.

```
s="hello(data=x, capitalize = True)there()my(x = x)dear(x, 6L, ...)friend(x = c(1, 2, 3))"
open_count = 0
close_count = 0
last_index = 0

rebuilt = []

for i, char in enumerate(s):
    if char == '(':
        open_count += 1
    elif char == ')':
        close_count += 1
    
    if open_count != 0 and open_count == close_count:
        rebuilt.append(s[last_index:i+1])
        open_count = 0
        close_count = 0
        last_index = i+1
    
print(rebuilt)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy as I said in the answer - extremely brittle. I also commented on the question to the same effect. I don't think there is a a "sensible" answer unless `regex` has better capabilities than I know about?

Comment: @KellyBundy nice to know you've got my back :D I think it would require the full R parser to work properly

Comment: @ KellyBundy could you post that snippet again? so I can check whether such a pattern exists in my data

Comment: @ORené `"hello('little)bobby(tables')"`

Comment: It's worth noting that this explodes this parser, and I fully acknowledge that) I'm not sure it would be syntactically valid in R so hopefully you're safe

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a comment that your input is actually a stream of R function calls, which means a Python parser may not work, but the same approach is valid if you can find an R parser that reports the same kind of information on a syntax error.

---

If you could assume that your string is syntactically correct Python code except for a lack of newlines between function calls, you can repeatedly parse the string, catching `SyntaxError` exceptions and using them to split the string into a valid function call and the remainder of the code to check.

```
from ast import parse

calls = []
while True:
    try:
        ast.parse(s)
    except SyntaxError as exc:
        i = exc.offset - 1
        calls.append(s[:i])
        s = s[i:]
    else:
        calls.append(s)
        break
```

Comment: interesting approach, but unfortunately the loop does not break on its own with the sample string I provided

Comment: This is an example where your example string is *not* syntactically valid Python code anymore. `6L` was valid in Python 2, but not Python 3 (which eliminated the distinction between the `int` and `long` types: no more `long` type, so no more long literals.)

Comment: As a result, this code treats `dear(x, 6` as a valid "call", with `L, ...)` as the remaining code. `L, ...` is a valid *expression*, leaving `)` to forever iterate as a null call followed by `)` to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [pypi/regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module (a regex module with more advanced features like references to subpatterns that allows recursion and backtracking control verbs).

```
import regex

s='''hello(data=x, capitalize = True)there()my(x = x)dear(x, 6L, ...)friend(x = c(1, 2, 3))
hello('little)bobby(tables')
'inastring(blablubli)'
'''

pattern = r'''(?x)
# subpatterns definitions
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<string> '{3} [^'\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^'\\]* | ''? (?!') [^'\\]* )*+ (?:'{3} | ['\\]* \z )
           | "{3} [^"\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^"\\]* | ""? (?!") [^"\\]* )*+ (?:"{3} | ["\\]* \z )
           | ' [^'\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^'\\]* )*+ (?:' | \z )
           | " [^"\\]*+ (?s: \\. [^"\\]* )*+ (?:" | \z )
  )

  (?<parens> \( [^'"()]*+ (?: (?&string) [^'"()]* | (?&parens) [^'"()]* )*+ (?: \) | \z )
  ) 
)

# main pattern
(?&string) (*SKIP)(*FAIL) # to ignore all that is in a string
|
\w+ (?&parens)'''

print(regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Note that this pattern is designed for the python syntax (with strings enclosed with 3 quotes), feel free to change the string subpattern according to the target language.

This pattern show you how you can deal with strings, in a same way you can add a support for comments.